# aggregate warnings results: jenkins postbuild action

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gnu-make, lint

Im using the [warnings](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin) plugin which works great for parsing various warnings in the console output. Particularly for gnu make and lint warnings.

What i would like to do is aggregate these upstream warning results to the parent job. Then include them in an email. I don't want the worker job (the one that generated the warnings) to send the email because of aggregation reasons (i need to combine multiple sets of job results).

There exists a junit plugin for the aggregation of test results, but I can't find an analogous tool for warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Archive the console log (or whatever has the warnings) in your downstream job. Then have your upstream job retrieve that file, and configure the Warnings plugin to parse the retrieved file(s)